# How do I copydoc from a C++ member group in doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have this code

```
    /**
     * @brief Class corresponding to the %PatientData schema type.
     *
     * @nosubgrouping
     */
    class __declspec(dllexport) PatientData: public ::abc::def::phsyiology::datamodel::ObjectData
    {
      public:
      /**
       * @name Name
       *
       * @brief Accessor and modifier functions for the %Name
       * required element.
       *
       * Identity of the patient
       */
      //@{

      /**
       * @brief Element type.
       */
      typedef ::xml_schema::string Name_type;

      //@}
```

I would like to use @copydoc/@copybrief/@copydetail to the documentation from the group  into documentation of another class, specifically I want the 'Identity of the patient' string used in another classes documentation.

I can grab the PatientData doc with
@copydoc abc::def::physiology::datamodel::PatientData

Since this is a member group I would think
@copydoc abc::def::physiology::datamodel::PatientData::Name
would work but it does not..